# Trying to remember the title of a sci-fi fantasy that involved a golem?

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

It was a fantasy sci-fi story. It had a female protagonist. She was a student. I think she was related to royalty and was banished to being a commoner.
There was a battle where they built a hot air balloon to help them in battle. They also were able to animate structures.

Could it have been *The Dark Tower* series?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F. When did you read this?  Was it a hardcover, paperback or e-book?  Do you recall the cover art?

Comment: My first impulse is Diana  Wynn Jones's *Year of the Griffin*, which has the daughter of a lord sent to Wizarding school, but I don't think there are any balloons, and there's only one mention of a golem.

Comment: Where and when did the golem come into play?

Comment: I think it's not Stephen King's Dark Tower series, as I do not recognize the details that you've mentioned.